# Are there function calls that can replace the for loops in this code?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

This code fragment is a bottleneck in a project of mine.  Are there function calls that could replace the for loops and speed it up?

```
D = np.zeros((nOcc,nOcc,nVir,nVir))
for i in range(nOcc):
   for j in range(i+1):
      tmp = Ew[i] + Ew[j]
      for a in range(nVir):
         tmp2 = tmp - Ew[a+nOcc]
         for b in range(a+1):
            tmp3 = 1.0/(tmp2 - Ew[b+nOcc])
            D[i,j,a,b] = Iiajb[i,a,j,b]*tmp3
            D[i,j,b,a] = Iiajb[i,b,j,a]*tmp3
            D[j,i,a,b] = D[i,j,b,a]
            D[j,i,b,a] = D[i,j,a,b]
```

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? and how big is `nOcc` and `nVir`?

Comment: What are nOcc, nVir, Ew, Iiajb...

Comment: probably more of a codereview question

Comment: you will need to better explain what you are trying to do ... but i would wager the answer is yes there is a better way to do it

Comment: You need to use better variable names.

Comment: Sure, you can reduce almost all of the cost of the looping by calling `map` with a flattened-out genexpr. But I sincerely doubt that's the bottleneck, unless maybe `a` is tiny.

Comment: So it looks like you are trying do some sort of quantum mechanical calculation in the chemist notation (maybe MP2?). This is very neat, but is awfully slow as written. As someone who does this quite a bit everything should be vectorized and use either `np.dot` which calls DGEMM or [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) whenever possible. As a note the variable names actually make a lot of sense if you do this kind of thing.

Comment: @John can you provide some dummy input data (e.g. some random values with the right kind of dimensions) so that this code runs (i.e. so that I can copy and paste this directly into an interpreter) and we can see your expected `D` output?

Comment: @Ophion you are right, this code calculates MP2 energy denominators. As you suggest, the integral transformation (not shown here) is done with np.einsum and is fast. But I can't see how do that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off lets generate some arbitrary data, thats obeys a few required principles:

```
nOcc = 30
nVir = 120
Ew = np.random.rand(nOcc+nVir)
Ew[:nOcc]*=-1
Ia = np.random.rand(nOcc)
Ib = np.random.rand(nVir)
I = np.einsum('a,b,c,d->abcd',Ia,Ib,Ia,Ib)
```

Lets wrap your base code as an example:

```
def oldcalc_D(Iiajb,nOcc,nVir,Ew):
    D = np.zeros((nOcc,nOcc,nVir,nVir))
    for i in range(nOcc):
       for j in range(i+1):
          tmp = Ew[i] + Ew[j]
          for a in range(nVir):
             tmp2 = tmp - Ew[a+nOcc]
             for b in range(a+1):
                tmp3 = 1.0/(tmp2 - Ew[b+nOcc])
                D[i,j,a,b] = Iiajb[i,a,j,b]*tmp3
                D[i,j,b,a] = Iiajb[i,b,j,a]*tmp3
                D[j,i,a,b] = D[i,j,b,a]
                D[j,i,b,a] = D[i,j,a,b]
    return D
```

Taking advantage of integral symmetry is typically a good tactic; however, in numpy alone it is not worth the cost so we are going to ignore this and simply vectorize your code:

```
def newcalc_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew):
    O = Ew[:nOcc]
    V = Ew[nOcc:]
    D = O[:,None,None,None] - V[:,None,None] + O[:,None] - V
    return (I/D).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Some timings:

```
np.allclose(oldcalc_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew),newcalc_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew))
True

%timeit newcalc_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew)
1 loops, best of 3: 142 ms per loop

%timeit oldcalc_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew)
1 loops, best of 3: 15 s per loop
```

So only about ~100x faster, as I said this is a fairly simple pass to give you an idea what to do. This can be done much better, but should be a trivial part of the calculation as the integral transformation is (O)N^5 vs this at (O)N^4. For these operations I use numba's autojit feature:

```
from numba import autojit

numba_D = autojit(oldcalc_D)

%timeit numba_D(I,nOcc,nVir,Ew)
10 loops, best of 3: 55.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

unless this is Python3, you may want to start by replacing `range` with `xrange`: the former creates the entire list, while the latter is just an iterator, which is all you need in this case.
For large `N`s, speed difference should be noticeable.

Also, seeing as your using numpy, there is probably a vectorized way to implement the algorithm. If that's the case, the vectorized implementation should be orders of magnitude faster. But unless you explain the variables and the algorithm, we can't help you in that direction.